# Как можно создать сессию $_SESSION['language'];?

Tags: php, сессия

Как можно создать сессию `$_SESSION['language'];` ?

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('Localhost', 'test2', 'test2') or die('cannot connect to db server');
mysql_select_db('test2') or die('cannot select database');

if(!preg_match('/^(ru)|(en)$/', $_GET['lang'])) {
    $lng = 'ru';
}
else {
    $lng = $_GET['lang'];
}

$trans = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT trans_section, trans_text FROM php_translate WHERE trans_lang = '$lng'") or die('cannot select language from database');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $trans[$row['trans_section']] = $row['trans_text'];
}
?>
```

При нажатии на ссылку начинается сессия

```
<a href="?lang=ru">Русский</a>
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше так, ведь нам надо сессию дальше использовать, и записать результат тоже нужно всегда.

```
<?php

session_start();

$link = mysql_connect('Localhost', 'test2', 'test2') or die('cannot connect to db server');
mysql_select_db('test2') or die('cannot select database');

if(!preg_match('/^(ru)|(en)$/', $_GET['lang'])) {
    $lng = 'ru';
} else {
    $lng = $_GET['lang'];
}

$_SESSION['language'] = $lng;
```

Answer (score 2):

В условие

```
else {
    $lng = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

Вставьте `session_start()`, а потом присвойте `$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang']`.

В итоге будет вот так выглядеть:

```
else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang'];
    $lng = $_GET['lang'];
}
```